# How can I use more than "return" statement in the following piece of code?

Tags: racket

In my else condition I have two statements to execute. The first one ought to append my calculation to my return-list and the second one calls my recursive procedure again.
The problem is that my append procedure is being ignored so I am just returning an empty list.

```
(define (calcit x lst)
    (cond ((= x 0)
           retlst)
           (else (append (list (floor (/ x (first lst)))) retlst)
                 (calcit (modulo x (first lst)) (rest lst)))))
```

Comment: Where is `retlist` defined?

Comment: Previously in code.

Comment: it is just
(define retlst (list))

Comment: Then of course it's empty when you return it. It's defined as empty, so it stays empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with the data you are creating. You probably want to have the first element consed on the result of the list you get from the recursion:

```
(define (calcit x lst)
  (if (= x 0) 
      '() ;; base case
      (cons (floor (/ x (first lst)))
            (calcit (modulo x (first lst)) (rest lst)))))
```

When creating lists in Scheme with recursion try to avoid `append`. Using `append` is an anti pattern. Learn how Scheme lists work and train to know it intimately. eg `'((2 3) (4 5))` if I ask you how to get `5` from that you should think d a d a and answer `cadadr` almost right away.